# Sporadic undeliverable mail notification on Courier mail server

Tags: email, ssl, email-server, courier

About 95% of outgoing mail goes through, but I get sporadic undeliverable mail notifications while trying to connect to other mail servers.

```
>>> STARTTLS
<<< 500 couriertls: connect: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

Courier 0.58.0
Courier Authlib 0.62.1
OpenSSL 0.9.8j

Where should I start to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a SSL version mismatch.  Looks like your server is trying to handshake mail in v3 format, when the receiving server probably only accepts v2.

You should try enabling both v2 and v3 handshaking for your server.

Comment: Strange enough I thought I had done that, esmtpd config file has a line TLS_PROTOCOL=SSL23 which means SSL23 - either SSLv2 or SSLv3. Will look further in that direction, thanks

Comment: I use this on my mailserver without a problem.

TLS_PROTOCOL=SSL3
TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL=TLS1

Answer (score 1):

make sure the following line is correct in /etc/courier/imapd-ssl:
TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL=SSL3